# Creating live windows usb with persistence storage

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows, live-usb, persistence

I'm looking for a way to create a windows 7/8/10 live usb with persistence storage. Recently, I started learning .NET and I have to create Windows Form Applications or ASP.NET Core web applications.  I tried to use some IDEs like Rider, QT and ..., but the problem is it wasn't useful at all. So, I don't want to try ways like VM or Dual-Boot installation and exactly, I need to create a live usb. I googled a lot and I couldn't find a solution. Thanks a lot :)

I would be interested if I can dual boot this drive with Ubuntu in the future.

Comment: I suggest making a full USB install. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1235490/1073514 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1217839/1073514

Answer (score 1):

### Windows to USB install

Rufus has an option to install Windows to Go to a USB.
This is just like running Windows 10 from a hard disk.

[image]

It may not work with acceptable speed on all flash drives. It worked good for me on a 64B Lexar.

I will try adding Ubuntu to the disk as dual boot.

Comment: I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: It took me all night to do the job.

Comment: Seems it will take all my time tonight. It's weird.

Comment: It took a lot of time but it eventually worked

Comment: I was unlucky, this way didn't work. When I try to boot, I see windows splash screen for one moment, but after it takes me back to the ubuntu.

Comment: Win to Go is picky about hardware, have you read: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the balena etcher app and download the windows ISO you want. Then run the balena etcher app which will make you a bootable USB stick.

Comment: Have you tried running Windows as a full OS doing this? I think this works as a Windows installer only.